# How to reliably block "Come here often ? Make Google your home page." popup?

Tags: firefox, spam-prevention, google-search, advertisements

When I do google search I see this popup from time to time on search results page in upper right corner:

[image]

From this [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34195660/72178) I knew that it's appearance depends on cookies set by google and indeed it appears constantly in Firefox private mode because cookies are not saved in this mode.

How can I block this popup or prevent it from appearing so that I can verify this in private mode ?
I have Adblock Plus installed but it does not block it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the rule blocking this popup in [Fanboy Annoyances List](https://easylist-downloads.adblockplus.org/fanboy-annoyance.txt). It can be added from [here](https://www.fanboy.co.nz/). For Adblock Plus users it is also necessary to uncheck "Allow some non-intrusive advertising" checkbox. See [this github issue](https://github.com/ryanbr/fanboy-adblock/issues/31) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

It appears from your question Firefox is the browser of choice. Don't have that, but as there is not enough rep in the kitty for comments, here's a solution for Edge users with an aversion to clicking nag pop-ups:
From BeanBrown's post at the end of [this thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/websearch/sc4M3UHaSa0) copy the following link and make that the home page:

```
https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl
```

One way to do this with Microsoft Edge 40.15063.0.0 is explained at [Wikihow](http://www.wikihow.com/Change-Your-Homepage-in-Microsoft-Edge).